# Query via collectionGroup by name

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

So as of May 8 2019, Firebase Firestore now supports querying sub-collections of the same name via `collectionGroup('collectionName')`.

Is there a way to retrieve multiple documents of the same `docId` across these sub-collections?

Here's a little visual example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
collectionA
  - documentA
    : collectionB
      - documentC
  - documentB
    : collectionB
      - documentC
```

Let's say I want to get both of those `documentC` documents. Is there a way to do so?

The current code I'm trying, to use is this:

```
const docIdFieldPath = FieldPath.documentId()
admin.firestore().collectionGroup('collectionB').where(docIdFieldPath, '==', 'documentC').get().then(...)
```

However I'm thrown an error of:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Resource name "projects/myProject/databases/(default)/documents/documentB" lacks "/" at index 86.
```

The docs on the matter say to create an index before attempting querying via `collectionGroup`, but if I try to do so via the online-index-portal I get an error saying that the `__name__` field is reserved.

Am I missing something silly, or is this feature not supported yet?

Comment: I get that error too, but I don't know if this is an intended feature or not.  FYI it appears you have an extra `collection("collectionA")` in your code.  Is that a typo?  I'd expect it not to work, as `collectionGroup()` is only a method on `Firestore`.  You can't constrain a collection group query to a subcollections of a particular collection.

Comment: Oops, good call @DougStevenson, that was a typo. But that's interesting to know that there's not a way to restrain `collectionGroups`! Are you saying that you're not sure on whether or not `collectionGroup` queries supporting `__name__` queries are a feature yet? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore collection group query on documentId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149601/firestore-collection-group-query-on-documentid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the Firestore team has told me that this isn't supported.  You can't filter based on the string of the document ID.  The mobile SDKs give you a nicer message, but apparently the nodejs SDK does not.

What you can do instead is store the id of the document as a field in the document itself, and filter on that field.