# How to get documents with specific id in different collections efficiently in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get multiple documents in my database that have been created with the same id. I know it's possible to do it using `collectionGroup` with the code presented bellow, but I am looking for a potentially more efficient and cleaner way to do it.

I have read this question [How to perform collection group query using document ID in Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188250/how-to-perform-collection-group-query-using-document-id-in-cloud-firestore) indicating that it is essential to store the id in a field to find the document by using  `collectionGroup`.

In my case, documents with `myId` can be in two different collections so I want to avoid using `collectionGroup` because I would have to do it on two separate collections like this:

```
const collectionOneDocs = await firestoreInstance.get().collectionGroup('collectionOne').where('id', '==', myId).get();
const collectionTwoDocs = await firestoreInstance.get().collectionGroup('collectionTwo').where('id', '==', myId).get();
```

This code works for me, but I would like to do a single operation to access the documents and also avoid saving the `id` as a field in the documents since it's not really necessary. So is there anyway in firestore to find all documents with a specific `id` or is this already the best solution available with firestore?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Answer below. But I'm not sure I understand why you don't want to have a single collection group. The whole purpose of their existence is so that you can query across multiple collections by giving them the same name.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the answer. I understand their purpose, but our DB is currently designed in a way that I need to query on those two group of collections with different names and changing this would take a lot of time so I was looking for an alternative solution. I'll just use the collectionGroup twice since it appears to be the best here. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the collections have different names, there's no way to get results from them with a single query.

So your only options are to:

- Either run a separate query for each collection (name).
- Give the collections the same name.