# Firestore query the documents in subcollections using their IDs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure of nested subcollections and documents. Each name of the documents in the `experience` subcollection represents `userId` of some user that has experience in that game.

[image: DB structure]

I have a converted that attaches this `userId` to the document:

```
experienceEntity.userId = snapshot.id;
experienceEntity.experience = snapshot.data().experience;
```

I want to query documents from all the `experience` subcollections of all the `games` that have a certain `userId`. E.g. I want to get all documents having `400riCGTB0YkxAF52maPUr5jKPN2` ID from the screenshot above. I was trying this:

```
const result = await firestore()
  .collectionGroup("experience")
  .withConverter(gameExperienceEntityConverter)
  .where("userId", "==", userId)
  .get();

return result.docs.map((snap) => snap.data());
```

... but it returns an empty array. If I remove the `where` clause - it returns all the documents from all `experience` subcollections without any filtering (there can potentially be millions of those at this point).

Comment: This query is looking for userId field in the sub-document. The converter just restructures the object you get. Also, querying based on document ID in a collection group query is not supported at the moment. It'll be best to add userId as a field in the sub-documents. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56188250/13130697) for more information.

Comment: You will need to add the document ID as a field of each experience document, then use that field as a filter in your collection group query.