# Firebase query by document id PLUS property value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am completely new to Firebase, maybe I just cannot search for the right keywords, but here's what I'd like to do:

I would like to read a document from the database by id, but only if that document has a specific property set. To be more specific, this would be something like a tiny blog server, where I want to read a post's data, but only if its "published" property is set to true. I don't want unpublished posts to end up on the client side.

I am using the JavaScript SDK, but can only find examples of lookup by either ID or properties...

Is this even possible?

---

UPDATE:
What I have now is (this is Firestore):

```
firebase.firestore().collection('blog-posts').doc(id).get()
```

and then later check for the property on the client side:

```
if (data && data.published === "true")
```

I would like all the filtering to happen on the server side.

Comment: Firestore or Realtime db? Can you post the relevant code you're currently using? Here's how to do compound queries in firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: "I don't want unpublished posts to end up on the client side." While Doug’s answer gives you the solution to write your query, be aware that it would be very easy for a user to read the posts that are not published just by removing the second where clause. In other words, if you want unpublished docs to be « un findable » (and not just filtered out by the query), you should, in parallel to the query, use a security rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a document only if a field has a certain value, you won't be able to use get() on its DocumentReference.  You will have to perform a query on the collection using both the document ID and field as filters on that query like this, using [FieldPath.documentId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#static-documentid):

```
const qsnap = await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('blog-posts')
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "==", id)
    .where("published", "==" true)
    .get()
```

This yields a QuerySnapshot, which you will have to check if the document was provided.

```
if (qsnap.docs.length > 0) {
    const doc = qsnap.docs[0];
}
```

Note that it still costs 1 document read to perform this query even if the document isn't returned.

Comment: Oh, wow this worked out of the box. Thanks, that ticks all the boxes for me!

Comment: Be very careful using this response - the FieldPath.documentId() used this way will **ONLY WORK IN TOP-LEVEL COLLECTIONS**.  It doesn't *actually* return the documentId; it returns the full path to the document, including all higher-level collections and documents.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` function to filter data on the server-side.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('blog-posts').where('published', '==', 'true').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', id).get()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to read one specific post by its ID. (I don't want a post to be readable when somebody guesses the doc ID)

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not easily let you filter/select on documentID; among other issues, FieldPath.documentId() returns the FULL PATH of the document, NOT just the id; see this question/answer for a fairly lengthy explanation of what *is* happening:

[Firestore collection group query on documentId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149601/firestore-collection-group-query-on-documentid/58104104#58104104)

it *is* possible to *also* copy the Id into a field in the document, and query by that (and I have my Firestore wrapper automatically helping with that) - BUT - this quickly become what I've seen called an "X-Y" question - asking "How do I do Y?" only because you already assume it's the answer to "How do I do X?"

The question is *why* do you want to query by the document ID?  Is this ID a proxy for some other information (such as a way to identify the user)?  If so, use the User ID as a field.  In general, the documentId is more about Google Firestore efficiently sharding their database for performance than as a real identifier.  Since the documentId is assumed to be unique (or, as the answer referenced explains, the **full path** to the document is unique), it's most often less useful for finding.

An analogy: using a documentId to find a document is like using a Municipal Parcel Number to designate an address.  Sure it's unique, but "Division 46675 Tract 32567 Parcel 12344" is a *lot* less useful than "450 Lazy Deer Road, Winnetka, New Jersey".

So: in your case, ask yourself: where *did* you get that documentId from?  What does it represent?  Can I store *that* in my document instead so I can use a compound query?

```
firebase.firestore().collection('blog-posts').where([whatever query identifies the document or documents]).where('published', '==', 'true').get()
```

Note whether your first condition identifies one or identifies multiple documents, the response object will include an **ARRAY**, which may have one or more documents in it.

The best general advice for Firestore and other NoSQL databases is to spend the time identifying exactly *how* you want to *use* your data - i.e. your queries - and build your structure to make *that* easier.  Remember, Firestore should be a tool to make *your* life easier, not to make *you* a slave to Firestore.