# Is it a bad idea to use the Firebase Firestore document Id in the frontend?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Should I create a different unique identifier to use in the frontend or can I use the auto generated Firestore ID? For example, I have a page that reads the ID in the URL and fetches the correspondent document. Should I use something else or is the id fine?

Comment: Using the ID is absolutely fine. Firebase IDs are unique and you should never have a problem when fetching a document

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using Firestore it is fine to use the auto-generated id.

Something to keep in mind is that you can't add it to a query (e.g. in a `where()`), you can only retrieve by pointing to the document (db.doc(`collection-name`/`doc-id`).get()) in the collection and getting it. This also means that you can't retrieve a subset of fields when retrieving a document using an id. I guess these points go with any id you use, auto-generated or not.

Comment: You _can_ use it in a query ```db.collection('books').where('__name__', '==' ,'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()```

Comment: `__name__`  does not just return/match the documentID.  It is essentially an alias for .documentID() fieldPath, which represents the FULL PATH to the document;the actual document path is just the last part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149601/firestore-collection-group-query-on-documentid/58104104#58104104

Comment: I didn't realize that existed, thanks folks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading about it and as long as the security rules are set it's fine to use the Ids in the frontend.