# How do I fetch documents with specific ids (plural) from a firestore collection using the `in` clause?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I already read few post on the topic, but for some reason I can not fetch the docs which I need. I have a collection `users` with auto generated id and each doc contains name and email. Here is my collection:
[image]

Please note, the ids are auto generated.

Then, what I try to do in the code is the following:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .where(
          "id",
          "in",
          ids
        )
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            const people = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
              people.push({
                  ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                  key: documentSnapshot.id
                  });
                });
              console.log("people: ", people);
          });
```

My `people` arrays is empty. I am pretty sure that my `ids` array has the correct ids. I am not sure if this part is correct:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .where(
          "id",
          "in",
          ids
        )
        .get()
```

Is `"id"` the correct name of the auto generated column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query a document by it's ID, you should make use of [`firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#documentid) which returns a special value that can be used with the `where()` filter to search by a document's ID.

---

The following code has been tweaked from [this documented gist](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/aea3bc9481bbab0a7fbc72069940e527) (Typescript/JavaScript):

```
function chunkArr(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) throw new Error("n must be greater than 0");
  return Array
    .from({length: Math.ceil(arr.length/n)})
    .map((_, i) => arr.slice(n*i, n*(i+1)))
}

async function fetchDocumentsWithId(collectionQueryRef, arrayOfIds) {
  // in batches of 10, fetch the documents with the given ID from the collection
  const fetchDocsPromises = chunkArr(arrayOfIds, 10)
    .map((idsInChunk) => (
      collectionQueryRef
        .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", idsInChunk)
        .get()
    ))

  return Promise.all(fetchDocsPromises)
    .then((querySnapshotArray) => {
      const allDocumentsArray = [];
      for (let querySnapshot of querySnapshotArray) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => allDocumentSnapshotsArray.push({...doc.data(), key: doc.id}))
      }
      return allDocumentsArray;
    });
}

const usersColRef = firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users");
const ids = [ /* ... */ ];

const docDataArray = fetchDocumentsWithId(usersColRef, ids);
```

If you were to use the unedited version of [the gist](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/aea3bc9481bbab0a7fbc72069940e527), you would instead use:

```
const usersColRef = firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users");
const ids = [ /* ... */ ];
const docDataArray = [];

await fetchDocumentsWithId(usersColRef, ids, (doc) => docDataArray.push({ ...doc.data(), key: doc.id }))

console.log(docDataArray)
```

Note: I'd avoid using the term "key" for Firestore and instead use "id". If you are using "id" in your documents, you could always use "_id" instead.

Comment: You'll want to review some limitation with the value created by firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() - it returns the FULL PATH to the document, not just the specific documentId https://stackoverflow.com/a/58104104/2434784

Comment: @LeadDreamer I'm not sure when, but that problem has been resolved since that answer was posted as the code included here works as intended. I'll see if I can find some information on when/how this was fixed which should be sometime between Jan and Jun 2020.

Comment: @LeadDreamer Following up on my previous comment, there are two modes of `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()`. When used on a `CollectionReference`, you specify just the document ID (e.g. `"c90QMzGbPSJA1qiQ95f6"`). However, when used on a collection group query you specify a valid document path (e.g. `"users/Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3/todos/c90QMzGbPSJA1qiQ95f6"`). This seems to be intended [based on the SDK tests](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/5ad7ff2ae955c297556223e6cb3ad9d4b897f664/packages/firestore/test/integration/api/validation.test.ts#L766-L792).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, and I'll make sure to update the gist with this info while the documentation on this feature is unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

In this situation I am assuming that `ids` is an array that you have in your client side code and are looking to query only for those ids in firestore?

Unfortunately, when using the `.where()` functionality in firestore, it does not query against the document ID's but rather the content of the document.

If you wanted to use the `.where()` indexing capability of firestore, you would need to add a `uid` field to the actual document data. Once you do that, you should be able to query for only the ID's you would like.

[From the firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: I see. Isn't that a bad practice? I mean, I have the ids one time, and then I put them second time. Or this is a standard practice? Tbh, I can't find any "easy" way of taking the docs which are in my array, apart of for loop and querying one by one?

Comment: Also, am I right that the column was named "id"?

Comment: The denormalization (repetition) of data is not bad practice in a NoSQL data structure such as Firestore. And no, you can not query against document ids beyond `firestore.collection('users').doc(<docId>)`.

Comment: @cpboyce While this was the case many years ago, there has been support for queries using document IDs since 2017.

Comment: @samthecodingman could you provide a link to where in the documentation it mentions that? Because I have not read about that and am interested to see.

Comment: @cpboyce Annoyingly it's not mentioned in the [guide documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), but has been around since v0.1.1 of the Firestore SDK ([Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_451_-_october_12_2017)/[GitHub Changelog](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/CHANGELOG.md#v011)). The reason I came across it is because it was finally added to the [documented API Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#documentid) last June.

Comment: This isn't the only thing that hasn't been updated in the guides either. The guide is yet to be updated to state that batched writes don't count [field transforms as two operations anymore](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_820_-_december_11_2020)