# How can I limit and sort on document ID in firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection where the documents are uniquely identified by a date, and I want to get the n most recent documents. My first thought was to use the date as a document ID, and then my query would sort by ID in descending order. Something like `.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId, descending: true).limit(n)`. This does not work, because it requires an index, which can't be created because `__name__ only indexes are not supported`.

My next attempt was to use `.limitToLast(n)` with the default sort, which is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

> By default, Cloud Firestore retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID

According to that snippet from the docs, `.limitToLast(n)` should work. However, because I didn't specify a sort, it says I can't limit the results. To fix this, I tried `.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId).limitToLast(n)`, which should be equivalent. This, for some reason, gives me an error saying I need an index. I can't create it for the same reason I couldn't create the previous one, but I don't think I should need to because they must already have an index like that in order to implement the default ordering.

Should I just give up and copy the document ID into the document as a field, so I can sort that way? I know it should be easy from an algorithms perspective to do what I'm trying to do, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it using the API. Am I missing something?

Edit: I didn't realize this was important, but I'm using the [flutterfire firestore library](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points.  It is ALWAYS a good practice to use random, well distributed documentId's in firestore for scale and efficiency.  Related to that, there is effectively NO WAY to query by documentId - and in the few circumstances you can use it (especially for a range, which is possible but VERY tricky, as it requires inequalities, and you can only do inequalities on one field).  IF there's a reason to search on an ID, yes it is PERFECTLY appropriate to store in the document as well - in fact, my wrapper library always does this.

the correct notation, btw, would be `FieldPath.documentId()` (method, not constant) - alternatively, `__name__` - but I believe this only works in Queries.  The reason it requested a new index is without the `()` it assumed you had a field named `FieldPath` with a subfield named `documentid`.

Further: FieldPath.documentId() does NOT generate the documentId at the server - it generates the FULL PATH to the document - see [Firestore collection group query on documentId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149601/firestore-collection-group-query-on-documentid/58104104#58104104) for a more complete explanation.

So net:

=> documentId's should be as random as possible within a collection; it's generally best to let Firestore generate them for you.

=> a valid exception is when you have ONE AND ONLY ONE sub-document under another - for example, every "user" document might have one and only one "forms of Id" document as a subcollection.  It is valid to use the SAME ID as the parent document in this exceptional case.

=> anything you want to query should be a FIELD in a document,and generally *simple* fields.

=> WORD TO THE WISE: Firestore "arrays" are ABSOLUTELY NOT ARRAYS.  They are ORDERED LISTS, generally in the order they were added to the array.  The SDK presents them to the CLIENT as arrays, but Firestore it self does not STORE them as ACTUAL ARRAYS - THE NUMBER YOU SEE IN THE CONSOLE is the  order, not an index.  matching elements in an array (`arrayContains`, e.g.) requires matching the WHOLE element - if you store an ordered list of objects, you CANNOT query the "array" on sub-elements.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found:

> FieldPath.documentId does not match on the documentId, but on the refPath (which it gets automatically if passed a document reference).

As such, since the documents are to be sorted by timestamp, it would be more ideal to create a `timestamp fieldvalue` for `createdAt` rather than a human-readable string which is prone to string length sorting over the value of the string.

From there, you can simply sort by date and limit to last. You can keep the document ID's as you intend.