# How to query Firestore subcollection's document's data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this data set:

```
authors - {name: "Author One"}
|_ categories - {label: "Category One"}
   |_ books - {title: "Book One"}
```

And I want to query all books of only "Author One".

I tried with `db.collectionGroup("books")` but it queries all books of all authors. This is the route `/authors/:authorId/books` and `:authorId` would be the Document ID of an author.

How do I query all books of an author by its Document ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a trivial case when using NoSQL, but there are multiple strategies to accomplish it:

=> "DeNormalize" your data - it costs you virtually *nothing* to include the authorId in each of the child documents (as they are created), allowing you to do simple collectionGroup queries to identify those "owned" by the author.

=> I will note, as shown, the path to your "books" is actually `/authors/:authorId/categories/:categoryId/books/:bookId`, but that requires specific authorId and categoryId.

=> a technique I *have* used (in fact built into a wrapper library I built for myself on npm, @leaddreamer/firebase-wrapper) takes advantage of the fact that the FieldPath `documentId()` (alternatively, "__name__") actually matches the **FULL PATH** to the document, not just the individual documentId (see here [Firestore collection group query on documentId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149601/firestore-collection-group-query-on-documentid/58104104#58104104)):

**NOTE BEFORE CODE**

This hack uses an inequality on the fullpath/documentId() Fieldpath.  As such, it limits other `.where()` clauses, and all inequalities must be on the same field.  Won't work in all cases; on the other hand, I use it fairly extensively on a deeply tree-structured database.

```
/**
 * @private
 * @typedef {Object} filterObject
 * @property {!String} fieldRef
 * @property {!String} opStr
 * @property {any} value
 */

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// convenience functions
/**
 * Contructs a filter that selects only the "owner" section of a
 * collectionGroup query - in other words, descendents of a particular
 * top=level document.  This takes advantage of Firestore's indexing,
 * which "names"/indexes all documents using the FULL PATH to the
 * document, starting from the top-most, i.e.:
 * TOP_COLLECTION/{dociId}/NEXT_COLLECTION/{docId}/NEXT_NEXT_COLLECTION/{etc}
 * This functions knowns NOTHING about the actual schema; it simply uses
 * the path of the indicated "owner" as starting portion of ALL the
 * "child" documents of the owner. It also takes advantage of the
 * strictly alpha-numeric nature of the path string.
 * As such, ALL children paths strings MUST be "greater than" the owner
 * bare path, and MUST be LESS THAN the alpha-numerically "next" value:
 * e.g. if the "owner" path is TOP_COLLECTION/abcdefg, then
 *
 * /TOP_COLLECTION/abcdefh > __name__ > //TOP_COLLECTION/abcdefg
 * (assuming LEXICAL SORT)
 * IMPORTANT NOTE:
 * Because this filter uses an INEQUALITY, .sortBy() conditions
 * are not supported
 * @function
 * @static
 * @category Tree Slice
 * @param {!Record} owner
 * @param {?filterObject} queryFilter additional filter parameters
 *
 * @returns {filterObject}
 */
export const ownerFilter = (owner, queryFilter = null) => {
  const ownerPath = owner.refPath;
  let nextPath = ownerPath.slice();
  const nextLength = nextPath.length;
  let lastChar = nextPath.charCodeAt(nextLength - 1);
  nextPath = nextPath
    .slice(0, nextLength - 1)
    .concat(String.fromCharCode(lastChar + 1));

  const ownerParts = [
    {
      fieldRef: "__name__",
      opStr: ">",
      value: ownerPath
    },
    {
      fieldRef: "__name__",
      opStr: "<",
      value: nextPath
    }
  ];
  return queryFilter ? ownerParts.concat(queryFilter) : ownerParts;
};

/**
 * Wrapper around database fetch, using ownerFilter above to
 * select/fetch just an "owner" parent document's descendants from a
 * collectionGroup
 * @async
 * @function
 * @static
 * @category Tree Slice
 * @param {!Record} owner
 * @param {!string} owner.refPath - string representing the full path to the
 * Firestore document.
 * @param {!string} collectionName name of the desired collectionGroup
 * @param {?filterObject} queryFilter filter parameters
 * @returns {QuerySnapshot} response
 */
export const querySlice = (owner, collectionName, filterArray) => {
  try {
    return collectRecordsInGroupByFilter(
      collectionName,
      ownerFilter(owner, filterArray)
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`failed:querySlice ${collectionName} err: ${err}`);
  }
};
```