# Where condition in firestore subcollection in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My data is stored in Firestore in below model.

My Problem is, I want to get **schoolid** of  logged-in email id.

***Data Model:***

```
instituteData->schoolid->users->email->data
```

***What I tried***

```
const q = query(collection(db, "instituteData"), where("email", "==", "abc@gmail.com"));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

**Screenshot of Data Structure**
[Screenshot of Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlNHY.jpg)

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your Firestore structure? It'll much more clear then as we can see where the email of school is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore queries can only filter on data in the documents that they return. So unless the `email` field is. inside the school documents, your query won't work.

The common workarounds are to:

- Replicate the email of each user in their school document, and using an `array-contains` query to then find the school.
- Using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) on all `users` collections to find the correct user(s), and then  going up the `ref.parent().parent()` chain of the document snapshots to find the school for each result.

Also see:

- [firestore query document that have a collection contains a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71215138/firestore-query-document-that-have-a-collection-contains-a-document/71215176#71215176)
- [How to query Firestore subcollection's document's data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68413385/how-to-query-firestore-subcollections-documents-data/68414334#68414334)
- [How to fetch all documents from a firebase collection where each document has some sub collection and in sub collection there is a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68998873/how-to-fetch-all-documents-from-a-firebase-collection-where-each-document-has-so/68999906#68999906)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no inner queries in firebase like we have in SQL, and your approach looks like the SQL table approach, clearly, your structure will not work well in firebase. You shouldn't make SQL-like structure in NoSQL, I learned this hard way.

one solution I can think of is to store the id of parent collections in child collection and all of their documents.
Basically, you are passing ids parent to all children. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

In your case
you should store `schoolId` in all its students, then you can directly get that document with `getDoc()` query and `schoolId` will be there already.

Hope this helps